# My android actionbar is not perfect

Tags: android-actionbar

I am using an actionbar in my app. But this actionbar is not displayed perfectly.

This is a picture of my actionbar:

[image: actionbar]

please help me ...

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This is impossible to help you with. We have no idea what is wrong with your action bar. Is the black bar the problem? State what you intend to achieve, and what is preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code for set Background image in actionbar

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgimage));
```

or

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bgimage));
```